# Iterate through an object- Android Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to go through an object which has an array within it containing names and numbers of -

```
 public void showPlayerGameList(){
        playerTextView = findViewById(R.id.aPlayerBox);

        for(PlayerDetails aPlayer : playerListGame.myPlayers) {

            playerTextView.append(aPlayer.name + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'java.lang.String com.example.android.footysortit.PlayerDetails.name'
>   on a null object reference

The way I am adding my player which is an object of PlayerDetails (which just contains a 2x String and an Int):

```
            if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
                PlayerDetails player = new PlayerDetails(); //TODO turn this into a loop to add each player the user picks and then display it
                player.name = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               // player.number =phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                playerListGame.addPlayer(player);
```

The idea is for the user to pick a contact and their name displays within a list but they can pick different contacts each time and each contact should be added to the list.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: debug and check that phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(); is returning someting or not

Comment: According to error message it's look like user object is null so when you try to access name field of null object you get NPE.

Comment: Can you show your PlayerDetails class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @contrapost3 - public class PlayerDetails {
    int id;
    String name;
    String number;

}

Comment: @SunilSoni The getString does return something. If i use the following:
                        playerListGame.addPlayer(player);
                        playerTextView = findViewById(R.id.aPlayerBox);
                        playerTextView.append(player.name);

It prints the name that I choose from the contacts list.

Comment: Therefore the only thing left we didn't see you initialise is `playerListGame.addPlayer(...)`. Where do you initialise the `playerListGame` Object? Try to log if it's value is null or not

Comment: @L.Spillner I initialise is globally within the same class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are adding your players, check that the result of `phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)` isn't null.

Currently it seems like a null value is set as the players name.

Perhaps there is another value you can try instead, or set the name to an empty string instead of null.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. If i use the follow:                         playerListGame.addPlayer(player);
                        playerTextView = findViewById(R.id.aPlayerBox);
                        playerTextView.append(player.name);
It works, so it shows that the player.name does hold a value.
The name will appear in the text view

Comment: are you setting the value of player.name anywhere else?

Comment: Good question, I actually made player global at the start, so I moved it into my function and made it local. So every time they choose a contact it will now pass through the name and if they do it again, it will print the second name on another line.

Comment: Do you make and add to playerListGame.myPlayers a PlayerDetails, without setting a name on it anywhere?

Comment: Yea, so I create playerListGame object from the class PlayerList( which creates array of PlayerDetails called myPlayers)
The idea is then to add a player to playerListGame with their contact details and then use playerListGame.myPlayers[i] to display their name.
So while writing this I just noticed that I should be using:
playerTextView.append(playerListGame.myPlayers[0].name+"\n");
and then maybe use a for loop to display the names....

Comment: Glad we were able to work through it!

Comment: Same here, thanks for your help!